# Text remains wrapped inside it's parent div - CSS, React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The question is pretty straight-forward and I have read lots and lots of posts about the same issue, though in my specific case all these solutions are not working because I am probably handling it wrong or making it over-complicated.

Some of the solutions I tried:

- [Why is this CSS nowrap not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150509/why-is-this-css-nowrap-not-working)
- [Let text go through a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200095/let-text-go-through-a-div)
- [CSS white-space nowrap not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164976/css-white-space-nowrap-not-working)
- [Don’t wrap span elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462741/don-t-wrap-span-elements)

Most of these posts come to the conclusion that you should use `inline-block` in combination with `white-space: nowrap`. Though after numerous trial and error tries, I actually kinda forgot what I did and did not try..

**My specific case**

I have a `React` application in which I want to display an `hours-bar`. This bar has a (sort-of) `table layout` but just with 1 `row`. The bar consists out of 15 cells (`div's`).

**The problem**

Each cell should have a specific text above it when a certain condition is met. So for example, I want to show a text value on the starting cell div, and the ending cell div and then each 5th cell again. It should look something like this:

[image]

I figured I could achieve this by making a 'Time' `row` inside the body of the time bar, however when I add it as a separate row, then the times / text will never be above the correct cells when the bar has multiple lines on the screen, you would then get something like this:

[image]

So my next idea was to make 2 separate div's inside the row where 1 div (the top div) functions as the header and the second div functions as the actual bar:

```
<TimeColumnBody>        
    <TimeColumnHeader>
        {(() => {
            if (item.showtime === true)
            {
                return <Test>{item.name}</Test>
            }
        })()}
    </TimeColumnHeader>
    <TimeColumn
        key={item.key} 
        name={item.name}
    >
    </TimeColumn>
</TimeColumnBody>
```

The above `html` get's rendered on each separate `cell` (time-step), so with the above example that would be 15 times (8:00 to 11:30 with steps of 15 minutes).

The objects `TimeColumnBody`, `TimeColumnHeader` and `TimeColumn` are created inside the `react file` and they are simple `custom div elements` with styling (using `styled-components`) :

```
const TimeColumnBody = styled.div`
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        width: ${props => (props.span ? props.span / 44 * 100 : "2.27")}%;
        height: 100%;
    }
`;

const TimeColumnHeader = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
`;

const TimeColumn = styled.div`
    height: 50%;
    background-color: red;
`;
```

The creating of the entire table / time-bar happens in the `React render` part:

```
render() {
        return (
                <TimeContainer>
                    <TimeRow>
                        {this.renderTimeTable()}
                    </TimeRow>
                </TimeContainer>
        );      
    }
```

The `renderTimeTable` function is the part where the cells are being created (`TimeColumnBody`, `TimeColumnHeader`, `TimeColumn` elements).

The text inside the `TimeColumnHeader` div remains wrapped inside the div even with the `white-space: nowrap;` property:

[image]

I tried adding the `white-space: nowrap;` property to the `TimeColumn` div with no effect, then I added the `display: inline-block property` with no effect, then I tried adding it to some `parent div's` but also without result.

The entire styling looks (currently) as follows (style added inline for easier reading):

```
<div class="App" style="text-align: center; height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <div class="Nav-LeftPane" style="width: 15%; height: 100%; position: fixed; box-sizing: border-box; overflow-y: auto; float: left;">...</div>
    <div class="content" style="width: 85%; height: 100%; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; float: right;">
        <div class="content-timebar" style="padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%; padding-top: 3%; height: 100%;">
            <!-- The actual Time Bar : --> 
            <div class="TimeContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 10%;">
                <div class="TimeRow" style="height: 100%;"> <!-- This div also has some :after logic: .TimeRow::after { content: ""; clear: both; display: table; } -->
                    <!-- the cell part which gets generated 15 times -->
                    <div class="TimeColumnBody" style="width: 2.222%; height: 100%; float: left;">
                        <div class="TimeColumnHeader" style="display: flex; align-items: flex-end; height: 50%; background-color: blue; color: white; white-space: nowrap;">
                            08:00
                        </div>
                        <div class="TimeColumn" style="height: 50%; background-color: red;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am now out of ideas and hope someone has a (better) solution to acheive this.

**UPDATE**

Added a CodePen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqJgRx

Comment: Do you have the html code to reproduce that last screenshot?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you can optimize the content inside the `TimeColumnHeader` tag by just doing `{item.showtime && <Test>{item.name}</Test>}` and removing the code that's in there. You're essentially creating, calling and destroying a function every time that particular part renders.

Comment: Thanks Sergio Moura, tips like that are always welcome since I am still very new to React! The HTML is posted in the bottom of the main post.

Comment: Place everything into a public CodePen so we can play around :)

Comment: As requested, the CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqJgRx also added the CodePen in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem initially appears to be related to overflow or wrapping, but it is actually a z-index issue - because you are floating `.TimeColumnBody` left, each subsequent element has a higher z-index than the last and thus overlaps the previous item. I was able to fix this simply by adding a `span` to the first time with:

```
.TimeColumnHeader span {
   position: absolute;
}
```

See pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOyZOx

Comment: Cheers! That fixed it :)